# Create and Edit Realm DB with Realm Browser on OS X

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-migration

Is there a way to create and edit Realm database on OS X, and then add it to the project?
I can't see any possibility to add i.e. more objects in Realm Browser.

Comment: Current Realm browser version not support, you can request this one to Realm team or make new one

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer on the Realm Cocoa team responsible for the Realm Browser!

At the moment, the Realm Browser lets you open a Realm file and edit existing values inside of it, but it doesn't let you create new Realm files just yet. This is something we're actively looking into. The Realm Browser is still very immature in regards to the amount of features it supports and we're looking at prioritizing the list of features we need to add to it.

If you've got a specific use-case you need in regards to the Realm Browser, I'd love to hear about it. Please head over to the [Realm Browser repository on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues) and file an issue!

Comment: How do you expect Realm to work initially? Should I create CSVs and SQLite, export them to Realm, fix all the relationships between objects, and then export the realm db? It seems like a lot to ask, to be honest, I mean once I have the SQLite db, I could just stop there.

Comment: At the moment, if you've got pre-existing data, yeah, we're recommending you write a small utility app to generate the initial Realm and import the data. It's not great, but it's necessary at the moment since we're still looking at ways to add this to the Browser in a user-friendly way. Yeah, that's true. You could just put it in a SQLite file, but the flip side of that is you then need to write all the boilerplate code to actually perform queries and access that data from within you app. ;)

Comment: I know and understand, however it seems mindblowing Realm doesn't have this tool yet. I've been asking around, and explaining the situation, and everyone seems shocked by it. Anyway, I will start writing my own tool or try using sqlite2realm (I understand there is such a tool)

Comment: Still nothing to create an empty realm and create class directly in the browser?